# How to get multiple outputs using classification techniques?

Tags: classification, python, natural-language, multi-class, multilabel

I want to predict `roles` based on `technical skills` column.I have column `technical skills` for which I have applied tf-idf to transform into numeric. I want to predict 5 roles for each observation.

Target Variable `Role` has 16000 unique values each observation has one role. (And I want to be able to predict the most likely 5 roles for each person)

Technical Skills are categorical (applied TF-IDF)

Can someone help me to find a solution. How can I approach this type of problem

Comment: How many data points do you have?

Comment: @StephanKolassa around 100000

Comment: That's probably not enough data to learn a 16000-way classification.

Comment: That is very little data if you have 16,000 possible targets. You could do a classification using a Random Forest. However, I would assume that there are many `technical skills` levels for which there are more than five `roles` - all of these will be equally valid predictions. Consider combining some `roles`.

Comment: How can I combine such `roles` because there are many combination of `technical skills` Can I use clustering here. Is it better than doing classification in this case. @StephanKolassa